# What happens to csproj on Azure DevOps buid

Tags: azure-devops

When building and publishing an Azure DevOps build, what happens to csproj and where does it go?

I'm writing data to csproj in AssemblyInfo Visual Studio marketplace but I can't seem to consume the data.

Comment: Hi, could you re-describe more details about scenario? You are building an Azure DevOps Extension or using the extension [Assembly Info](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=bleddynrichards.Assembly-Info-Task)?

Comment: Yes, I'd like to write the version number to AssemblyInfo - seems it won't let me because I'm in .NET Core (Blazor). So I tried to write to csproj, but, I don't know how to actually pull that data out in a compiled app and display it on the UI

Comment: Hi, do you mean that write the version number to .scproj file and read it in the build pipeline then pass it to AssemblyInfo?